# Uploading Image to server from android application

Tags: android, image, httpwebrequest, put

I am developing small android application in which I want to upload my image to my server with put method and image as body of request with json object.I refereed lot of questions regarding this and That help me a lot.I tried it in following way...

```
class ImageUploadTask extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, Void>{
    @Override
      protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {

         HttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String message;
            HttpPut p = new HttpPut("https://abc.com");
            JSONObject Jobject = new JSONObject();

            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);

            byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();

            Jobject.put("Image", data);


        try {
        message = Jobject.toString();

        p.setEntity(new StringEntity(message, "UTF8"));
        p.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            HttpResponse resp = hc.execute(p);

            if (resp != null) {
                if (resp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 204)
                {

                }
            }

            Log.d("Status line", "" + resp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        return null;


    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... unsued) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        try {
            if (dialog.isShowing())
                dialog.dismiss();

        } catch (Exception e) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error"+e,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
}
```

But it's Not working. when I tried to execute my network call it showing me system error 
`java.net.UnknownHostException: abc.com`. My I doing something wrong. Is there any way to do this. Need help. Thank you.

Comment: Did you provide correct link

Comment: which link? My api link right?

Comment: You might be missing the INTERNET permission.

Comment: Verify whether you provided permission

Comment: Are you able to access your server from device default browser?

Comment: thank you for help. I got it. I define permission in to manifest file and now its not showing error. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

im trying to do the same maybe we can help us, here is my code:

```
private class UploadFileToServer extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    Bitmap image;
    String name;

    public UploadFileToServer(Bitmap img, String name){
        this.image = img;
        this.name = name;

    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //creation of bytearray
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        guardem al byteArrayOutputStream anterior
        this.image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
        //codifing image
        String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(),Base64.DEFAULT);
        //array list creation and add what we want to send
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> dataToSend = new ArrayList<>();
        dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image",encodedImage));
        dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name",this.name));
        //i have dont understand so much from here to down....
        HttpParams HttpRequestParams = getHttpRequestParams();

        //send data by post server adres is my local api "ip/myapi/index.php"
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(HttpRequestParams);
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(SERVER_ADRESS+"index.php");

        try{
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(dataToSend));
//i take this part from you i hope it will work not tryied yet
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
            if (response != null) {
                if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 204)
                {
                      //so when you are here its all right?
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    private HttpParams getHttpRequestParams(){
        HttpParams HttpRequestParams = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(HttpRequestParams, 1000 * 30);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(HttpRequestParams,1000*30);
        return HttpRequestParams;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "image uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: i get the code from a youtuber but it not works, do you know if i have to send back response from php or its automatically done by the server ?

Comment: o lol i didnt read thad so little commets you solved that sorry for posting this i'll try your full code